# Django: how save bytes object to models.FileField?

Tags: python, django

My web application has the following structure:

1. backend with Django
2. frontend with React.

I have a form with React. I send a file from client form and I receive the file in my Django application with an APIView.

I receive a m3u file as bytes object.

```
b'------WebKitFormBoundaryIaAPDyj9Qrx8DrWA\r\nContent-Disposition: 
form-data; name="upload"; 
filename="test.m3u"\r\nContent-Type: audio/x- 
mpegurl\r\n\r\n#EXTM3U\n#EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="" tvg-name="...
```

I would save the file in a Django model to a models.FileField and convert bytes object to m3u file.
How you do it?

Answer (score 39):

1. `models.FileField`(`models.ImageField`) needs `django.core.files.base.File` like objects
   ex)

   - `django.core.files.base.File`
   - `django.core.files.images.ImageFile`
2. `File` or `ImageFile` needs two args.

   1. IO object : which has `seek()` method (ex) `io.BytesIO`).
   2. name : `str`. (important! without name, it will not work).
3. bytes object doesn't have IO's methods(ex) `seek()`). it should be converted to IO object.

---

models.py

```py
class Message(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='message_image/%Y/%m', null=True)
```

---

views.py or consumers.py or some-where.py

```py
import io
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
from myapp.models import Message

def create_image_message(image_bytes):
    image = ImageFile(io.BytesIO(image_bytes), name='foo.jpg')  # << the answer!
    new_message = Message.objects.create(image=image)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is correct and working answer.

Comment: Really nice explanation.

Comment: The enclosing BytesIO doesn't work (at least on Python 3.8, Django 3,2).  Creating the ContentFile gives the error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO'`

Comment: @Zags you're right. `ContentFile` is a special subclass of `File` class which takes just raw content. That was an inappropriate example. I have fixed the answer to the appropriate example, `File` class. Thanks for the advice! 
If `ContentFile` is used, ```content_file = ContentFile(some_bytes, name='foo.jpg')```

Answer (score 11):

You can try:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import base64

file_data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(fileData))
object.file.save(file_name, file_data)
```

You can use your file_name with an .m3u extension, and you shall have it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using temporary file. I used this code:

```
extM3u = str.encode(body.decode('utf8').split('EXTM3U\n#')[1].split('------WebKitFormBoundary')[0])

fileTemp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True, dir='media/tmp')
fileTemp.write(extM3u)
filenameRe = re.compile('.*?filename=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]')
filename = regParse(filenameRe, body.decode('utf8'))
file = File(fileTemp, name=filename)
m3u = M3u(titleField=filename, fileField=file)
m3u.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/#storage-objects).  To do so:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

content_file = ContentFile(file_bytes, name=file_name)
# Assumes MyModel has a FileField called `file`
MyModel.objects.create(file=content_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

convert string to bytes

```
bytes_data = ... # bytes

string_data = bytes_data.hex() # this is a string that you can save in TextField in django model
```

then, to get bytes from the string:

```
bytes_data_2 = bytes.fromhex(string_data)
```

*I apologize for the crooked translation, I'm still only learning English.*

Comment: dont save files in to text fields